# I have a problem with using firebase in unity, could not locate google-services.json or GoogleService-info.plist files

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I downloaded sdk in the official way, but could not find the file.

My error:

```
Could not locate google-services.json or GoogleService-Info.plist files.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Those files are specific to your project. You have to get one of those files from the [Firebase console](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) and add it to your project. You can follow the setup steps in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#prerequisites).

Comment: android is ok can execution and success,but ios have problem

Comment: The setup is different for Android and iOS.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, the way to ask is not good
My problem is that my file is downloaded and imported, but unity is not read.